# Unable to install ruby-1.9.3-p385 using RVM on Maverick

Tags: ruby, rvm

I apologize in advance.  I messed up my RVM, and have spent 4 hours looking at RVM documentation and Googling for the answer.  Thanks for any help that you can give!  Whenever I try to install ruby-1.9.3-p385 I get this error:

```
Welcome Master Josh!~/ziplist (master)$rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p385
ruby-1.9.3-p385 - #removing src/ruby-1.9.3-p385..
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.9/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p385.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' are already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/JKEMP/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p385 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p385, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p385 - #extracting ruby-1.9.3-p385 to /Users/JKEMP/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p385....
ruby-1.9.3-p385 - #applying patch /Users/JKEMP/.rvm/patches/ruby/GH-488.patch.
ruby-1.9.3-p385 - #configuring.
Error running './configure --prefix=/Users/JKEMP/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/libksba:/usr/local/opt/openssl --without-tcl --without-tk --disable-install-doc --enable-shared',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/JKEMP/.rvm/log/1412284154_ruby-1.9.3-p385/configure.log
[2014-10-02 17:09:27] ./configure
current path: /Users/JKEMP/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p385
GEM_HOME=/Users/JKEMP/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@ziplist
PATH=/Users/JKEMP/.rvm/usr/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/pkg-config/0.28/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/libtool/2.4.2/bin:/usr/local/opt/automake/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/autoconf/2.69/bin:/Users/JKEMP/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@ziplist/bin:/Users/JKEMP/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/bin:/Users/JKEMP/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/bin:/Users/JKEMP/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/JKEMP/node_modules/jshint/bin/jshint:~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3:/Users/JKEMP/bin:/Users/JKEMP/node_modules/jshint/bin/jshint
GEM_PATH=/Users/JKEMP/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@ziplist:/Users/JKEMP/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global
command(7): ./configure --prefix=/Users/JKEMP/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/libksba:/usr/local/opt/openssl --without-tcl --without-tk --disable-install-doc --enable-shared
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --without-tcl, --without-tk
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin13.4.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin13.4.0
checking target system type... i386-apple-darwin13.4.0
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/JKEMP/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p385':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely an issue where your Xcode is out of date.  Did you just upgrade to Mavericks?  If so, run this:

```
xcode-select --install
```

It will take some time, then you can run your rvm install.

If that doesn't work, try:

```
rvm install ruby-1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang
```